# java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: testng

lang.nullpointerexception while running the below code.

```
package aditi;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class TestNG {

    public static WebDriver driverok ;

@Test
  public void main(){
    driverok.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("addnfmdsn@hotmail.com");
    driverok.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Aasds");
    driverok.findElement(By.id("u_0_2")).click();
     System.out.println("login successfully");
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe\\");
        WebDriver driverok = new ChromeDriver();
      driverok.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
      driverok.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      driverok.quit(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: There are numerous similar questions here. with answers.

Answer (score 2):

On your *beforeMethod*, you are creating a local object:

```
WebDriver driverok = new ChromeDriver();
```

This object is alive during the *beforeMethod*, but sent to the garbage collect right after.

In the *main* method, you are referencing to the instance *driverok* object, which was never initialized (*null* by default). Therefore, when you try to call *findElement* on null, you get a *NullPointerException*.

Changing the *beforeMethod* to the following will initialize the instance property, making the *main* method work correctly:

```
this.driverok = new ChromeDriver();
```

See this answer to more information about `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728075/2252076